# How do I zero-pad a number converted from decimal to 16-bit binary in PHP?

Tags: php

I know how to do that simply with

```
str_pad(decbin($number),16,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

However, it appears that using

```
printf("blah",$number)
```

should do this faster, but I have no clue what the **"blah"** formatting characters have to be.
As this will have to be done millions of times, any speed-up is useful.
The only example I found used **"%08b"** to zero-pad to 8-bit a decimal number converted to binary.
And no, "%016b" doesn't work. All other examples avoid going beyond 8 bits.
The PHP.NET manual is just gibberish to me.

Answer (score 0):

For me `%016b` *does* work:

```
<?php
$number = decbin(11);
printf("%016b",$number);
```

The output I get is:

```
0000001111110011
```

This is PHP-7.0.18 on a x86-64 Linux system.

Comment: binary 0000001111110011 is 1011 decimal, so your result is not correct.

Comment: Ok, if that is a limitation of your platform, then the `strpad()` alternative sounds just great.